# How to add ListsService service reference in visual studio 2012?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to follow the tutorial @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pstubbs/archive/2010/10/04/developing-windows-phone-7-applications-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

At some point he suggested to add Service Reference tools in Visual Studio to add a reference to the Lists.asmx Web Service. If I right click project->add service reference.. Add service reference window pop up. I don't see any way to add Lists.asmx Web Service. This tutorial is bit outdated for windows phone 7. I want to make it happen for windows phone 8.

Could you please suggest me how could you add it?

Or how can I achieve the same goal for windows phone 8?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow bellow step

**Step1:** Add Service References by right click on add References.

**Step2:** Now put your web service link on Service References and press go button, And also add Namespace of service Reference 
[image]

**Step3:** Now add using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` name space in your .cs file

**Step4:** Now add bellow code in your cs file

```
 WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
ws.ContactUsJSONCompleted += ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted;
ws.ContactUsJSONAsync(txtContactUsName.Text, txtContactUsPhone.Text, txtContactUsEmail.Text, txtContactUsComment.Text);
```

**step6:** now genrate your resopnce method

```
 void ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted(object sender, dynamic e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(LogIn.NetworkBusyMsg, LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                string Result = e.Result;
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Result);
                string ResultCode = (string)obj["ResultCode"];
                string ResponceMessage = (string)obj["ResponseMessage"];

                if (ResultCode == "1")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your message. We'll get back to you soon.", LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

If any query than comment here.I wll help you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand Setp 2. I guessed I have to implement WhatsupServices.asmx and host it in the local machine. Then references   it form my phone application. Is my assumption correct? If yes how should I implement WhatsupServices.asmx? I'm new in windows world. Please help me. Thanks for the hints.